# Java memory consumption for Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, memory

I have the following piece of code,It just opens a JTextPane in a Jframe..

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class TextPane extends JFrame{
    public static TextPane instance;
    private static JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    private static JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextPane.getInstance().init();
            }
        });
    }
    private static TextPane getInstance() {
        if(null == instance){
            instance =  new TextPane();
        }
        return instance;
    }    
    private void init() {
        pane.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.setBackground(Color.black);
        pane.setForeground(Color.white);
        pane.setCaretColor(Color.green);
        pane.setDragEnabled(false);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) pane.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        scroll.setViewportView(pane);
        add(scroll);     
        setTitle("Dummy");
        setSize(500 , 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To analyze memory used by application i ran this code and once the GUI comes i verified Memory(Private working set) in Task manager ,(By right click on this application in Task manager Application tab and Go to Process).

For simply opening the GUI it showed around 16000K . is it normal?? If not how can i check the actual memory usage, which we can say this is the memory used by this application(For opening GUI).

Please help.

Comment: I got 40k, so yeah, I guess

Comment: I got 26K. Be sure you are looking at the right process.

Comment: You can use JConsole to monitor resource consumption of your app: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: You can't use the Task Manager to tell what memory a Java application uses.  When a JVM starts up it reserves enough space for the maximum heap plus other things like permgen etc.  In general, the important thing to look at is the size of the heap while your application is running and how much of it is consumed and how often the garbage collector is having to run

Comment: @MadProgrammer just 40K??? or 40000K ?

Comment: @user1803551 i right clicked the application and clicked on Go to Process..

Comment: @NickHolt Thanks.. i will check the heap usage using NetBeans profiler.. BTW in task manager sometimes the process shows java.exe and sometimes it is javaw.exe .. what difference does it makes?

Comment: @madhu the two executables are basically the same thing, the only difference being that `java.exe` displays the console output, while `javaw.exe` doesn't

Comment: @NickHolt As you said using Jconsole heap usage for GUI took ly 5MB..but in a case, When i keep on append something to Jtextpane(it has a document listener to limit 1000 lines) though the number of lines reaches 1000 and removes old text , the Task manager Memory(Private working set) keeps on increasing and it never stops..Can you pls explain why this happens??

Comment: @madhu you shouldn't focus on the native process, it's not going to tell you much - there's a lot more happening that just the part you're focusing on in your code and the JVM process may increase the memory being used to accommodate this.  Even looking at the heap in terms of lines being added to a `JTextPane` is not really much use because the memory management in a JVM is non-deterministic.  What you should be looking at, if you want to get an idea of what you application is doing is, to start with, the Monitor tab in Visual VM that will show the heap usage and GC taking place